# How do I get around that Google App Engine does not support writing files?

Tags: google-app-engine

I have a GAE/Python application that is an admin program that allows people all over the  world to translate template files for a large GAE application into their local language (we cannot use auto translation because many idioms and the like are involved).  The template files have been tokenized and text snippets in the various languages are stored in a GAE datastore (there are thousands of template files involved).

I therefore need to be able to write files to a folder.

I have the following code:

```
with open("my_new_file.html", "wb") as fh:
    fh.write(output)
```

I have read that GAE blocks the writing of files.  If that is true, is there some way to get around it?

If I cannot write the file direct, does anyone have a suggestion for how I accomplish the same thing (e.g. do something with a web-service that does some kind of round trip to download and then upload the file)?

I am a newbie to GAE/Python, so please be specific.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Is it a requirement that the files must be on the filesystem? I do something similar but I store my files in the datastore (and blobstore if they are larger than 1MB). You can pull template data from anywhere and render it within a GAE app.

The Titan Files library can abstract the writing of files to datastore/blobstore for you:
http://code.google.com/p/titan-files/

Answer (score 2):

you could use google app engine blobstore or BlobProperty in datastore to store blobs/files

for using blobstore (up to 2GB)
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/

for using datastore blobs (only up to 1MB)
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/typesandpropertyclasses#Blob

Comment: You can also take a look to Google Cloud Storage (https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/googlestorage/).

Comment: Not quite, you need to enable billing in your Google APIs Console project (not in GAE), and there is a free quota of 5GB until the end of this year.

Answer (score 0):

Filesystem is read only in many cloud system and GAE is too. In a virtual world, where the OS and machine are virtual, the filesystem is least reliable place to store anything

I would suggest using any of BLOB, Google Cloud Storage, Google Drive or even go a setp further and store in any external provider like Amazon S3 etc.

Comment: GAE filesystem is not ephemeral, it's read-only. You'll get an exception trying to write to it.

Answer (score 0):

Use the files API:
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/googlestorage/overview

Adding some extra code you can use it like the normal Python file API:

```
with files.open(writable_file_name, 'a') as f:
  f.write('Hello World!')
```

While this particular link describes it in relation with Google Cloud Storage (GCS) you can easily replace the GCS-specific pieces and use blobstore as a storage backend.

The code can be found here:
http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/python/google/appengine/api/files/